# MySQL - Get the max count from a subquery group

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table `logins` with the following schema:

```
| id | user_id | weekday |
|----|---------|---------|
|  1 |       1 |       1 |
|  2 |       1 |       2 |
|  3 |       1 |       2 |

...
```

Weekday is a number from 0 to 6.

I want to get which `weekday` has the highest count, for each `user_id` in the table.

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT MAX(num) as max_num, user_id, weekday
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) as num, user_id, weekday
    FROM logins
    GROUP BY user_id, weekday
) C
WHERE user_id = C.user_id AND num = C.num
GROUP BY user_id;
```

Which gets me `weekday = 1` instead of `2`. I think that I shouldn't use a `WHERE` clause here, but I couldn't manage to get the correct result.

I've checked other similar questions with no luck, such as:

- [MYSQL, Max,Group by and Max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15679857/mysql-max-group-by-and-max)
- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

I created a SQL Fiddle with my example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e43a71/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method:

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(num) as max_num, 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(weekday ORDER BY num DESC), ',', 1) as weekday_max
FROM (SELECT user_id, weekday, COUNT(*) as num
      FROM logins l
      GROUP BY user_id, weekday
     ) uw
GROUP BY user_id;
```

Comment: Note that `count(*)` may not always work perfectly in InnoDB due to a bug that is just now fixed in MySQL 5.7.19.  I had this problem earlier. Seems to be working ok after upgrading to 5.7.19.    https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-19.html

Comment: @Marc . . . You really prefer the other answer to this one?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT days.user_id, days.weekday, days.num
FROM (
    SELECT user_id, MAX(num) AS num
    FROM (
      SELECT user_id, weekday, COUNT(*) AS num
      FROM logins
      GROUP BY user_id, weekday
    ) max
    GROUP BY user_id
) nums
JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, weekday, COUNT(*) as num
    FROM logins
    GROUP BY user_id, weekday
) days ON(days.user_id = nums.user_id AND days.num = nums.num);

-- With Mariadb 10.2 or MySQL 8.0.2
WITH days AS (
    SELECT user_id, weekday, COUNT(*) as num
    FROM logins
    GROUP BY user_id, weekday
)
SELECT days.user_id, days.weekday, days.num
FROM (
    SELECT user_id, MAX(num) AS num
    FROM days
    GROUP BY user_id
) nums
JOIN days ON(days.user_id = nums.user_id AND days.num = nums.num);
```

Comment: If you have Mariadb 10.2, or MySQL 8.0.2+ you can write better and shorter query using window function, or WITH statment.